# C++ redefinition error, Why am I getting this error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I had a redefinition problem but I noticed that I already included .cpp file in the .hpp file so my mistake was including the .hpp file in my .cpp file again
Now I am getting this error, something to do with templates.
Also while you fix my problem, can you explain to me what template class does?
cplusplus.com is not that descriptive.
Thank you. :)

```
//implementation
template<class T>
ArrayBag<T>::ArrayBag() : item_count_(0){}
```

-------------WARNING YOU ARE NOW LEAVING IMPLEMENTATION---------------------------

```
//interface
    #ifndef ARRAY_BAG_H
#define ARRAY_BAG_H
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class ArrayBag
{
    protected:
        static const int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 200;
        T items_[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
        int item_count_;
        int get_index_of_(const T& target) const;
    public:
        ArrayBag();
        int getCurrentSize() const;
        bool isEmpty() const;
        //adds a new element to the end, returns true if it was successfully been added
        bool add(const T& new_entry);
        bool remove(const T& an_entry);
        void clear();
        bool contains(const T& an_entry) const;
        int getFrequencyOf(const T& an_entry) const;
        std::vector<T> toVector() const;
        void display() const;
        //overloading operators for objects
        void operator+=(const ArrayBag<T>& a_bag);
        void operator-=(const ArrayBag<T>& a_bag);
        void operator/=(const ArrayBag<T>& a_bag);
};

#include "ArrayBag.cpp"
#endif
```

-------------WARNING YOU ARE NOW LEAVING INTERFACE---------------------------

```
//error
5 C:\Users\minahnoona\Desktop\ArrayBag.cpp expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token 
5 C:\Users\minahnoona\Desktop\ArrayBag.cpp expected `;' before '<' token
```

Comment: You shouldn't really include cpp file in header file, could you share your cpp here?

Comment: the errors you get are from .cpp file, not .hpp you've shared

Comment: The problem may be that you are including cpp file in hpp file, and the hpp file in cpp file, causing some compile problems.

Comment: There is a list of good books [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2):

Don't call your `ArrayBag.cpp` a `.cpp` file. Template implementations go in header files, and the name should reflect that.

If you want the implementation in a separate file (you don't strictly need to), call it `ipp` or `tpp`. Something the project system won't try to compile on its own.

Then include it from the `.hpp` and don't include the `.hpp` from the `.ipp`.

Comment: You could've mentioned that that the cpp file is separately compiled and causes trouble.

Comment: @Red.Wave -- I don't see anything in the question that suggests that the cpp file is being compiled separately. But if that's the case, since it has only the definition of a template function, it's harmless.